# vlc player doesn't run with optirun

Tags: vlc, bumblebee

I have installed bumblebee. Other applications are working with `optirun` instead of vlc.

```
optirun -b primus vlc
```

## error

```
VLC media player 2.0.8 Twoflower (revision 2.0.8a-0-g68cf50b)
[0x19d0108] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
../../../include/vlc_xlib.h:46:vlc_xlib_init: Xlib not initialized for threads.
This process is probably using LibVLC incorrectly.
Pass "--no-xlib" to libvlc_new() to fix this.
[0x1d8e5e8] qt4 interface error: Xlib not initialized for threads
../../../include/vlc_xlib.h:46:vlc_xlib_init: Xlib not initialized for threads.
This process is probably using LibVLC incorrectly.
Pass "--no-xlib" to libvlc_new() to fix this.
[0x1d8e5e8] skins2 interface error: Xlib not initialized for threads
[0x1d8e5e8] skins2 interface error: initializing xlib for multi-threading failed
[0x1d8e5e8] skins2 interface error: cannot initialize OSFactory
[0x1d8e5e8] [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
VLC media player 2.0.8 Twoflower
Command Line Interface initialized. Type `help' for help
```

## System info

```
Ubuntu 13.10 (64bit)
optirun (Bumblebee) 3.2.1
```

Is there any workaround?? Thanks..

## Edit

**This issue fixed in** `VLC media player 2.1.6`

Answer (score 0):

This is saying that it doesn't support the GUI of VLC but wel on command line. You can play , for example a video, if you put the file name as a a parameter:

optirun vlc /path/of/gamesofvideo.mkv

The problem is that is very painful to use vlc in text mode :-(

Answer (score 0):

Good news. I found a solution. In order to launch VLC through Bumblebee without errors - VLC must be installed BEFORE Bumblebee.

P.S. I tested it two times on Ubuntu 14.04 ([Run VLC via Bumblebee](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635356/run-vlc-via-bumblebee))

Comment: Actually there is no such things. VLC media player 2.1.6 fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, but the following command worked for me:

```bsh
optirun -b none vlc
```

Answer (score -2):

(this would be a comment, but I need 50 reputation before I can post comments.)

I have vlc working on Ubuntu 12.04 with Bumblebee, although I can't get it if I enable primus bridge. `optirun vlc` seems to work fine though. Does it fail if you let it set bridge as auto with just `optirun <app>`?

Comment: optirun vlc has the same error. Other application is working with optirun app

Comment: I assume you have tried both `--no-xli` and using cvlc. https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=86906 . Try updating with `apt-get`, and if that still fails, try getting a new version directly http://www.videolan.org/vlc/

Comment: I have installed latest version from ppa but no luck

Comment: I found a commit of vlc about --no-xlib but don't understand how to pass it as argument. vlc --no-xlib also show the same output as optirun vlc   https://mailman.videolan.org/pipermail/vlc-commits/2010-June/001799.html