# Run VLC via Bumblebee

Tags: nvidia, vlc, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

When I try to run VLC through the commands optirun or optirun -b primus using the command line I get the following output:

```
VLC media player 2.1.6 Rincewind (revision 2.1.6-0-gea01d28)
[0xd35118] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
../../../include/vlc_xlib.h:46:vlc_xlib_init: Xlib not initialized for threads.
This process is probably using LibVLC incorrectly.
Pass "--no-xlib" to libvlc_new() to fix this.
[0x1216418] qt4 interface error: Xlib not initialized for threads
../../../include/vlc_xlib.h:46:vlc_xlib_init: Xlib not initialized for threads.
This process is probably using LibVLC incorrectly.
Pass "--no-xlib" to libvlc_new() to fix this.
[0x1216418] skins2 interface error: Xlib not initialized for threads
[0x1216418] skins2 interface error: initializing xlib for multi-threading failed
[0x1216418] skins2 interface error: cannot initialize OSFactory
[0x1216418] [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
VLC media player 2.1.6 Rincewind
Command Line Interface initialized. Type `help' for help.
```

Who knows what the problem is. My system is Xubuntu 14.04.2 64-bit, installed packages: nvidia-331, bumblebee, bumblebee-nvidia, primus, sni-qt:i386 (for Skype), IDE Qt Creator 5.4 x64.

The paradox is that in the old system before reinstalling at the same identical configuration across vlc optirun worked fine, but now does not.
I will be glad to any advice, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Good news. I found a solution. In order to launch VLC through Bumblebee without errors - **VLC must be installed BEFORE Bumblebee.**

P.S. I tested it two times on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

It is working but on command line... Add only the file name to open something:
optirun vlc /path/of/gamesofvideo.mkv

Seeing a video on command line is not very handy.

Comment: Nope, I don't want watch movies in command line :) The VLC Player should run FROM command line using nVidia card for render video.